# Linking definition lists (best practice) or bad idea?

Tags: html, css, list

What is the best practice for linking dl list items ([Definition lists](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/definition/))

```
<dl>
    <dt>link title 1</dt>
    <dd>link description 1</dd>
    <dt>link title 2</dt>
    <dd>link description 2</dd>
</dl>
```

linked(?):

```
<dl>
    <a href="#">
      <dt>link title 1</dt>
      <dd>link description 1</dd>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <dt>link title 2</dt>
      <dd>link description 2</dd>
    </a>
</dl>
```

or would you use `<li>` and `<br>` tags to achieve a similar thing.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">link title 1<br><span class="description">link description 1</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link title 2<br><span class="description">link description 2</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

This is for what is to become part of a mobile app (via phone gap) any help or insight would be brilliant, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use `a` tag as direct child of `dl`. The `dd` and `dt` tags are used as direct child. So, you can use:

```
<dl>
      <dt><a href="#">link title 1</a></dt>
      <dd><a href="#">link description 1</a></dd>

      <dt><a href="#">link title 2</a></dt>
      <dd><a href="#">link description 3</a></dd>
</dl>
```

This way you maintain the standard of html.

Comment: So same "practice" as li and ol then. Great! thanks, heaps just what I needed. I was Surprised to google it and not find an answer (or on stack.) but this explains why, ha.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HTML5 doctype then you can do the following

```
<dl>
    <a href="#">
      <dt>link title 1</dt>
      <dd>link description 1</dd>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <dt>link title 2</dt>
      <dd>link description 3</dd>
    </a>
</dl>
```

However if you're not then the above won't be valid as `dd` is a block level element and putting it inside an `a` which is an inline element will cause your HTML to become invalid

Comment: I am using html5 so this will work then. thanks, Pattle!

Comment: You can use `a` tag in any tag according to html5 but `a` tag as direct child of `dl` tag would still be invalid....